# How to pass a variable from one function into another using MatLab?

Tags: function, matlab, variables

Let's say I have some function `import_data()` and inside of this function I am creating 2 variables: `response_values` and `file_to_get`

```
file_to_get = uigetfile({'*.csv*'}, 'Select the CSV File',...
'\\pfile01thn\bbruffey$\My Documents\analysis data\full files\...
Raw Stats Data full file only');

response_values = zeros(numel(C),numCols);
for i=1:numel(C)
    v = textscan(C{i}, '%s', 'Delimiter',',');
    v = str2double(v{1}(4:end));
    response_values(i,1:numel(v)) = v;
end
```

I then need these variables passed into another function `MS_Banding_Streaking()`

How could this be done? (I'm using globals at the moment which is extremely bad practice.

Comment: Unless I misunderstood the question, can't you just assign the variables you want as the outputs of `input_data()` and then pass them to `MS_Banding_Streaking` in the standard way as in my answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like

file import_data.m

```
function response_values, file_to_get = import_data()

file_to_get = uigetfile({'*.csv*'}, 'Select the CSV File',...
'\\pfile01thn\bbruffey$\My Documents\analysis data\full files\...
Raw  Stats Data full file only');

response_values = zeros(numel(C),numCols);
for i=1:numel(C)
    v = textscan(C{i}, '%s', 'Delimiter',',');
    v = str2double(v{1}(4:end));
    response_values(i,1:numel(v)) = v;
end
```

file mainfunc.m

```
% Stuff before
[vals, filegot] = import_data()
MS_Banding_Streaking(filegot, vals)
% Stuff after
```

Comment: @BenB.: `ins` was a generic variable name in case your import_data function was to take inputs... if you don't need it just remove it, i.e. `function response_values, file_to_get = import_data()` ...

Comment: oh okay, i do have options that i have implemented for plotting but I'd remmoved them thinking i needed this haha. okay

Comment: @BenB. - I modified my code to reflect the fact that you didn't need any inputs to input_data

Answer (score 1):

Just simply write the two functions in the same `.m` file

```
function import_data()    
file_to_get = uigetfile({'*.csv*'}, 'Select the CSV File',...
'\\pfile01thn\bbruffey$\My Documents\analysis data\full files\...
Raw  Stats Data full file only');

response_values = zeros(numel(C),numCols);
for i=1:numel(C)
    v = textscan(C{i}, '%s', 'Delimiter',',');
    v = str2double(v{1}(4:end));
    response_values(i,1:numel(v)) = v;
end

MS_Banding_Streaking(response_values, file_to_get);

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

function MS_Banding_Streaking(resp_value, f2g)
% function body
```

Comment: So since the function `import_data()` is creating the variable `response_values`  if i understand your example correctly, i should just be able to add it in `MS_Banding_Streaking(response_values)` and it should work.  Right now running my code this way it is telling me that the variable `response_values` is undefined.

Comment: @BenB. You should call `MS_Banding_Streaking` inside `import_data` since `response_values` is created within `import_data`

Comment: Note though that doing this this way means that you can't call `MS_Banding_Streaking` from anywhere other than this file.

Comment: That's the issue I see with this, since i have a main function that is calling both `import_data()` and `MS_Banding_Streaking()`

Comment: @BenB. actually you can put the `MS_Banding_Streaking` function in a seperate file, as long as it's in the same directory as the main function file and the `import_data()` file, you should be able to call it in both main function and the `import_data()`.

Comment: Yes chaohuang, that's the answer I posted ^.^